# How to reduce php page loading time?

Tags: php, web, execution

I have created webpages for a Magazine in PHP. I have called header and footer files in each page. My pages are having only HTML codes except header and footer files. Even though my page loading time is too long. Can any one help me to solve my problem. I am very new to PHP so i dont know the tricks.

Comment: The server doesn't have to make a request if the PHP-code requires the header and footer since the code is internal (The server only have to request the files from its own harddrive) hence the server will not be slower by 'require' nor 'include'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this page: http://www.webpagetest.org/ it measures the performance of your generated output (html).

Everything else like slow php execution times cannot be measured by observing the frontend properly. You will have to gain some skills and tools to profile your php application and see what is actually slow. The standard procedure is googling for `optimizing php scripts` or `profiling a php script`, etc. You probably will need to invest money to get some proper tools.

PHP must not even be the culprit here. Long server response, bad mysql queries, etc may impact execution and delivery speed.

Answer (score 1):

use a good web server with caching frameworks like opcache. Reduce the file sizes of images, javascript, css. Avoid unneeded loops. 
That are some examples. It depends on what you do.